# Identifying an orange flowery shrub

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

Me again. Anyone has an idea of what this is? Thanks a lot.

As a sidenote, the images make the flower look more yellow than they are. In reality they are orange.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems the pleniflora cultivar might be what I'm looking for. What about the difference in color, though? Is it known to appear in different colors? This is also from someone's yard, and was also collected in south-central Europe.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks a lot! Why don't you post an answer so I can mark it as correct?